# Proper Sentence building

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I want to know how to structure a sentence properly?

The situation is in my office, a meeting was postponed twice and now we are rescheduling it for the third time.

I want to know how to draft an email, in which I need to inform all the employees about the rescheduled meeting with the new date and timing.

Furthermore, in the email, I want to highlight that this meeting was continuously getting postponed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Dear colleagues,
>
> The meeting that was set to take place at (...) this morning/afternoon,
>   after it had been postponed twice, has once again been rescheduled.
>   Please be informed that the meeting will now be held at (...).

How about that?